# I cannot extend the class in java

Tags: java, mysql, extends

This is may one class.
Now i want to create a new class `registrationvalidator` extending `LoginValidator`.
i tried by

```
public class registrationvalidator extends LoginValidator {

}
```

But its show error in netbeans...What is the soluation?

```
public LoginValidator() throws SQLException{

    try {
        connect = new Dbconnect();
        st = connect.Statement();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

public int validator(String mobileNo,String pass){
    int ret = 0;
    try{

        String query="select * from login where mobileNo='"+mobileNo+"'";
        res= st.executeQuery(query);
        while(res.next()){
            String dbMobileNo=res.getString("mobileNo");
            String dbPass=res.getString("password");

            if(mobileNo.equals(dbMobileNo) && pass.equals(dbPass)){
                ret=1;
            }
            else if(mobileNo.equals(dbMobileNo)){
                ret=2;
            }
        }


    }catch(SQLException ex){
        System.out.println("Sql Execption: "+ex);
        System.out.println("3"); 
    }

    return ret;
}
}
```

Comment: `But its show error in netbeans` - **which** errors do you get?

Comment: Without actually seeing the error, I would "guess" that because the default constructor of `LoginValidator` throws an `SQLException`, Java expects that the `registrationvalidator` default constructor should either throw the same exception or handle it...

Comment: I must say, you don't have any uniformity when it comes to follow some sort of coding conventions.

Comment: The whole structure is wrong. You have a partial method signature `public LoginValidator() throws SQLException{` Which in real life would need a return type or void, however you state that you want LoginValidator to be a class.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A few things here.

1. You can only define one public class per java file. So your RegistrationValidator class should be in its own java file, separate from the LoginValidator class.
2. Since you are catching the SQLException and logging some info, you don't need the "throws SQLException" for the constructor signature LoginValidator()

Comment: There is only one class listed in the question.